# Open browser from another browser

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, url, browser

I can open Telegram using `tg:` URL scheme, open Edge by `microsoft-edge:`.
But how to open other browsers?

```
window.location = "tg://resolve?domain=VulpesDust"; // work
window.location = "microsoft-edge:"; // work
window.location = "googlechrome:"; // not work
window.location = "google:"; // not work
```

If you now how to open browsers on some page (example.com or google.com) it will helpful

Errors in Firefox:

- Prevented navigation to “googlechrome:” due to an unknown protocol.
- Prevented navigation to “google:” due to an unknown protocol.

Errors in Google Chrome, Microsoft Edge and Opera:

- Not allowed to load local resource: googlechrome:
- Failed to launch 'firefox:' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.
- Failed to launch 'google:' because the scheme does not have a registered handler.

Comment: Telegram and Edge appear to have registered custom protocols on the host system.  There's no guarantee that any other browser or application has done that, unless you have a reference to any information indicating otherwise.